# dbms_stats.gather_table_stats resulting in Deadlock

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms, oracle12c

I have a scenario where in gathering stats on 2 child tables in parallel is resulting in a deadlock contention and there by a job failure.

When I say child tables, both of them have got same parent table with FK defined on them referring to same parent keys as well.

Database is on 12.1 version RAC with 2 instances. Is this an expected behavior or any suggestions to overcome this please.

Comment: It's not expected behaviour. Diagnostic information for any deadlock should be in the alert log.

Comment: Let me quickly have a look at it

Comment: please paste the deadlock key information, the information will be in alert log and related trace file.

Comment: I know it's been quite some time, I didn't have access to alert log as the DBAs were reluctant to share and just told me that they didn't notice anything. But then what I essentially did to prevent this error is to not have child tables to have stats gathered in parallel. The only error message that I was able to capture was `"ORA-20005: object statistics are locked (stattype = ALL)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_STATS", line 34634
ORA-06512: at "my_custom_package.proc", line 793
ORA-06512: at line 220
"`